# Exercise about Christoffel symbols: prove that $\Gamma^k_{ij}(p)+\Gamma^k_{ji}(p)=0$

Tags: differential-geometry, geodesic, connections

Let $\nabla$ be a linear connection on a manifold $M$.

I want to prove that:

$$\Gamma^k_{ij}(p)+\Gamma^k_{ji}(p)=0,$$

if in $p\in M$ normal local coordinates are defined.

I have a solution which involves the use of a geodesic curve, using the exp map, but I do not understand the connection with the normal coordinates. Could you please give me some hints to resolve this problem?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n$ be normal coordinates centered at $p$. I am going to show that $$\Gamma_{1 2}^k(p) + \Gamma_{2 1}^k(p) = 0$$
for $k=1,\cdots,n$. The general case i.e. replacing $1,2$ by $i,j$ is analogous. Being normal coordinates mean that the curve $ \gamma: t \to (t,t,0,0,\cdots)$ is a geodesic. Then the velocity vector of $\gamma$ at $p$ is parallel w.r.t. itself. Namely $$\nabla_{\gamma'} \gamma' = 0 \, .$$
Now notice that $\gamma' = \frac{\partial}{\partial x_1} + \frac{\partial}{\partial x_2}$. So at $p$ $$\nabla_{\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1} + \frac{\partial}{\partial x_2}} (\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1} + \frac{\partial}{\partial x_2}) = \nabla_{\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}}(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}) + \nabla_{\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}}(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_2}) + \nabla_{\frac{\partial}{\partial x_2}}(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}) + \nabla_{\frac{\partial}{\partial x_2}}(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_2}) = 0 \, \, .$$

Also the curves $(t,0,\cdots,0)$ and $(0,t,0,\cdots,0)$ are geodesics. So you also have at $p$ $$ \nabla_{\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}}(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1})  = \nabla_{\frac{\partial}{\partial x_2}}(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_2})  = 0 \, .$$
Then you get at $p$ $$\nabla_{\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}}(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_2}) + \nabla_{\frac{\partial}{\partial x_2}}(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}) = 0$$
Taking components w.r.t. $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_k}$ you get $$\Gamma_{1 2}^k(p) + \Gamma_{2 1}^k(p) = 0 \, \, .$$

Comment: Thanks! I would ask you another question: why the curve $ \gamma: t \to (t,t,0,0,\cdots)$ is a geodesic ? Which is the correct definition of normal coordinates?

Comment: By normal coordinates I understand the coordinates given by the exponential map as in Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_coordinates